# Force explicit template instantiation with CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp

I am trying to use a CRTPed base to hold some static initialization code like this:

```
template <typename T>
class InitCRTP
{
public:
static InitHelper<T> init;
};

template <typename T> InitHelper<T> InitCRTP<T>::init;
```

Now, any class which needs to do the work in `InitHelper<T>` can do this:

```
class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>
{
  public:
  void dummy(){init;}//To force instantiation of init 
};
template class InitCRTP<WantInit>;//Forcing instantiation of init through explicit instantiation of `InitCRTP<WantInit>`.
```

To force instantiation of `InitCRTP<WantInit>::init`, I can either use `dummy` or use the explicit instantiation as shown above. Is there a way of getting around this with doing neither? I would like users of this pattern to be able to simply inherit from `InitCRTP<WantInit>` and not worry about anything else. If it helps, using `C++11` is not an issue.

Comment: [temp.inst]/2 about *implicit* instantiation: "Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; **in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist**."

Comment: You could try odr-using `init` in a virtual member function of the base class template.

Comment: "any class which needs to do the work in `InitHelper<T>`..." Well, `InitHelper` isn't a template in this design, so i have no idea what that means.

Comment: @WhozCraig error while translating my code to an sscce. Fixed.

Comment: @Pradhan ah, ok, that make much more sense. f'ing html-tag smartums sometimes aren't so smart =P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could pass the variable as a reference template argument. Then the object is needed which causes an instantiation

```
template <typename T, T /*unnamed*/>
struct NonTypeParameter { };

template <typename T>
class InitCRTP
{
public:
     static InitHelper init;
     typedef NonTypeParameter<InitHelper&, init> object_user_dummy;
};
```

Comment: It is beautiful and it works for g++.  Strange, it seems to not want to work for VS2017.  It might be a compiler bug.   I created a new question to discuss this in   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953599/force-template-instantiation-success-at-g-fail-at-visual-c    Perhaps, you may shed light on it.