# Force template instantiation via typedef template<typename T, T> - why it works?

Tags: c++, crtp, template-instantiation

I am learning forcing template instantiantion.
It works, but I am still curious :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <typename T, T>struct NonTypeParameter { };//#1#
int lala=0;
template <typename T> class InitCRTP{
    public: static int init;
    public: using dummy=NonTypeParameter<int&, init>;   //#2#
};
template <typename T> int InitCRTP<T>::init = lala++;
class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>{
};
int main(){
    std::cout << lala << std::endl;
}
```

It prints 1, because `InitCRTP<WantInit>::init` is instantiated correctly.

**Observation**

1. If I remove the line `#2#`, it will print 0.  (`InitCRTP<WantInit>::init` is not instantiated).
2. If I change `#2#` from `int&` to `int`, I will get :-

   > error: the value of 'InitCRTP::init' is not usable in a constant
   >   expression
3. If I change `#1#` to `template <T>struct NonTypeParameter { };` and `#2#` to `public: using dummy=NonTypeParameter<init>;` I will get :-

   > error: 'T' has not been declared

### Question

1. Why the line `#2#` is enough to force instantiation?
   In my opinion, it is just a typedef *within template class* that is not accessed by anyone.
2. Why do I need `int&` as another template parameter to make it compilable?
   A probably more correct question : What is the name of the technique?

Original post : [Force explicit template instantiation with CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725152/force-explicit-template-instantiation-with-crtp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the line #2# is enough to force instantiation?

To supply the second argument, the compiler has to bind a reference. Meaning it ODR-uses the static variable, so the variable has to exist and have a unique identity. Ergo, its definition is instantiated.

When you use plain `int`, the second parameter can only accept integer constant expressions. A non-const static is not usable in a constant expression.

> Why do I need `int&` as another template parameter to make it compilable?

You need to declare the type of the reference for the second parameter to have a type the compiler can check against. Well, prior to C++17 you needed to anyway. Nowadays we can use a placeholder type instead.

```
template <auto&>struct NonTypeParameter { };//#1#
using dummy=NonTypeParameter<init>;//#2#
```

That will ODR-use the passed in static without having to specify a reference type explicitly.

Comment: Thank.  Nice answer.    Do you happen to have some reference for the strange behavior "Ergo, its definition is instantiated"?

Comment: Thank, your quote in another post about https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2  make me rest in peace.

Comment: @StoryTeller: What do you make of the apparent implication of [temp.inst]/2–3 that such a member type alias shouldn’t be eagerly instantiated?

Comment: @DavisHerring - I make it wording issue. It shouldn't be merely apparently implied either way. And I'm in the camp that agrees with GCC and Clang's implementation. Whether or not it's correct should be made explicit

Comment: @StoryTeller: It seems related to CWG2335 to me, in that a case can be made for instantiating such things “as needed”.  Of course, one can always force the “needed” part with a member declaration that uses the type alias.  It might meanwhile interest you to see an [alternative I concocted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58316729/8586227) based on what is certainly instantiated.