# Force template instantiation via typedef : success at g++ , fail at Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++17, template-instantiation

I want to force template instantiation.
The below code works (print `1`) at g++ ( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33986d0e0d320ad4 ).
However, it prints wrong result (`0`) at Visual C++ ( https://rextester.com/WGQG68063 ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <int& T>struct NonTypeParameter { };

//internal implementation
int lala=0;
template <typename T> struct Holder{
    static int init;
};
template <typename T> int Holder<T>::init = lala++;

//tool for user 
template <typename T> struct InitCRTP{ 
    using dummy=NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>;
};

class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>{};//user register easily
int main(){
    std::cout << lala << std::endl;
}
```

Is it a Visual C++ compiler bug, or a kind of undefined behavior?
If it is Visual C++ bug, how to workaround it (while still keep it beautiful)?

**Edit:** Change class -> struct  as Max Langhof (and many people) recommended. Thank.

### **Bounty Reason**

With opposite solutions from ***StoryTeller*** and ***Maxim Egorushkin*** and their in-depth discussion (thank!), this sounds like a fuzzy area of C++ rule.

If it is Visual C++ bug, I wish the issue to be certain enough to report.

Moreover, I still wish for a nice workaround, because this technique is very shiny for custom type-id generation.  Explicit instantiation is not so convenient.

**Note:** I awarded bounty to ***Kaenbyou Rin***, because, for me, it is easy to understand.
It doesn't means that the rest of answers are less correct or less useful.
I am still not sure which is a correct one.   Readers should proceed with caution.
For safety, I will assume that I just can't use the feature (for now).  Thanks  everyone.

Comment: Note: The _"minimal"_ in _"minimal reproducible example"_ does not stand for _"use as little whitespace and newlines as possible"_ ;) Also, please don't do per-line `public:` just because you want it to look like Java - that's decidedly not "beautiful". Consider using `struct` instead of `class` for e.g. `Holder` to get default-public visibility of its members.

Comment: I personally consider [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) better readable (and thus more 'beautiful') than all those variants keeping opening braces on same line. Have no official statistics available, but that seems to be a majority oppinion, especially among C++ and C coders.

Comment: Godbolt link for convenience: https://godbolt.org/z/THyLe1

Comment: Cannot remember anything about in the standard, possibly that's simply unspecified? *If* so, no bug in either compiler...

Comment: Explicitly using the class *might* give you desired results (need to test yourself, no MSVC available). Are you aware that if you apply this pattern in different compilation units, order in which these initialisations occur is unspecified? So if you just want unique ids for your classes, that's fine, if you want some specific order, you're out.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yes, I am aware that the order is unspecified.  I have a mechanism to handle it. Thank for your concern. :)

Comment: General advice: Are negative ids meaningful? If not, I'd prefer `unsigned int` to explicitly express that.

Comment: @Aconcagua I use negative for debugging, like -1234 = error.   I agree that `unsigned int` (or even `unsigned short`) is generally better for type ID.

Answer (score 6):

There is a compiler bug involved, for sure. We can verify it by changing `InitCRTP` a bit:

```
template <typename T, typename = NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>>
struct InitCRTP {
};
```

Now referring to any `InitCRTP<T>` specialization must use `Holder<T>::init` to determine the second template argument. This in turn should force an instantiation of `Holder<T>::init`, and yet [VS doesn't instantiate that](https://rextester.com/live/TUHS1438).

In general, using the CRTP class as a base should have instantiated all the declarations inside the class, including that of `dummy`. So that too should have worked.

We can verify it further. Declarations of member functions are instantiated along with the class, when used as a base:

```
template <typename T> struct InitCRTP{
    using dummy=NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>;
    void dummy2(dummy);
};
```

Still, [VC++ is stubborn](https://rextester.com/live/YNQBK40483). Given all of this, and the behavior exhibited by both Clang and GCC, this is a VC++ bug.

Comment: What would that compiler bug be?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Not instantiating what is clearly ODR-used now

Comment: Where is `Holder<T>::init` ODR-used?

Comment: `typename = NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>` - `NonTypeParameter` accepts a *reference*

Comment: `NonTypeParameter` is not ODR used because `InitCRTP<WantInit>::dummy` isn't either.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - The declaration of `dummy` is instantiated, because to use a type as a base requires a completely defined object type, and that instantiates **all the declarations** in the class.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation:  _unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated, and does not require a definition._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - That is about member functions and other minutia. But the declarations of those *are* instantiated, and for a type alias a declaration is always a definition too, so that's instantiated as well.

Comment: Nothing refers to template member type `InitCRTP<WantInit>::dummy`, hence it doesn't get implicitly instantiated. A `typedef`/`using` name is a member: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Keep repeating that if you can't let it go. Either way, the standard [is explicit](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2) about what definitions are not instantiated, aliases are not in the list.

Comment: That standard paragraph mention explicitly what gets instantiated and the instantiation of member `typedef`/`using` members is not in the list, I am afraid.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - No it mentions that the declarations are instantiated, but not the definitions of select special members. I suggest you reread it.

Comment: Read its first sentence carefully: _the declarations (but not of the definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers) of the class member functions_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - *but not the definitions of <list that includes member functions>*. Now I'm done, feel free to have the last word if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Note: `/permissive-` does not seem to fix it for MSVC.

Comment: You may like to file a bug report against the compiler then.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am sorry for being so thick, please bare with me. In that huge standard paragraph you refer to, there is a very specific list of things which get implicitly instantiated. Type aliases are not in that list, as far as I can understand. What particular words in that paragraph require type aliases to be instantiated, could you post those particular words please?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - You know what. Your insistence is making me have doubts. Perhaps both "declarations" and "definitions" apply to the list. In which case, it is only the next paragraph that specifies where a type alias declaration is instantiated. Maybe I've been taking "declarations are instantiated" for granted. But I am certain that in the *modified* pieces of code I posted, it is a VC++ bug. Both the default template argument and the function type parameter are instances where `init` should have been instantiated.

Comment: You should post a bug report and get a definite answer. Claiming it is a bug with no bug report isn't credible.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - Bug to whom? VC++ operates one way, GCC and Clang another. So opinions obviously differ. There's plenty of "credibility" to go around.

Comment: @StoryTeller [How to report a problem with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 4):

`class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>` does neither instantiate `InitCRTP<WantInit>::dummy`, nor `Holder<WantInit>::init` because they aren't referred to by something *actually* used in the program. The implicit instantiation chain in your code doesn't require instantiating `Holder<T>::init`, see [implicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Implicit_instantiation):

> This applies to the members of the class template: **unless the member is used in the program, it is not instantiated, and does not require a definition.**

A fix is to use [explicit template instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation):

```
template struct Holder<void>;
```

That causes `Holder<void>` to be instantiated along with all its non-template members.

Alternatively, you can instantiate just `Holder<T>::init` member, e.g.:

```
static_cast<void>(Holder<void>::init);
```

---

IMO, gcc and clang are overly eager to instantiate things that aren't referred to. Such a behaviour doesn't break or reject valid code, so that is hardly a bug, but depending on such a specific behaviour for side effects is brittle and non-portable.

Comment: This makes me kinda sad.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725152/force-explicit-template-instantiation-with-crtp  (just an example, not an official rule), it should work.

Comment: @javaLover @javaLover The implicit instantiation chain in your code doesn't require instantiating `Holder<T>::init`, that is why the example you cite doesn't apply.

Comment: Does `using dummy=NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>;` (where `NonTypeParameter` takes an `int&` template argument) not take a reference to `Holder<T>::init`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof `dummy` isn't referred to, hence it doesn't get instantiated implicitly.

Comment: In the example I cited (in Johannes Schaub - litb's answer), `object_user_dummy` is not referred too.

Comment: Do you think that it is undefined behavior?

Comment: @javaLover What exactly?

Comment: My program : it can print 0, or 1 on different compilers.  Is it a result from an undefined behavior?

Comment: @javaLover IMO, `gcc` and `clang` are overly eager to instantiate things that aren't referred to. Such a behaviour doesn't reject valid code, so that is hardly a bug, but depending on such a specific behaviour for side effects is brittle.

Comment: Thank.  It is useful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to definitely ODR-use the `init` member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int lala=0;
template <typename T> struct Holder{
    static int init;
};
template <typename T> int Holder<T>::init = lala++;

template <typename T> struct InitCRTP{
    InitCRTP() { (void)Holder<T>::init; }
};

class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>{};
int main(){
    std::cout << lala << std::endl;
    // WantInit w;  <---------------------------- look here
}
```

Now the outcome of the program changes if the commented-out line is uncommented. IMHO template instantiation status or ODR-use status of anything cannot possibly depend on whether or not some non-template function (the WantInit constructor in this case) is called. I would say there is a rather strong smell of a bug.

Comment: There is a standard complaint method to detect whether a template has been instantiated. Cannot quite find the link right now...

Answer (score 1):

<s>I believe @MaximEgorushkin is right about the fact that `dummy` is not really instantiated.</s>

`dummy` is declared (because it is a type alias **declaration**), and in order to declare this alias, `NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>` is declared. In order to declare `NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init>`, its template parameter `Holder<T>::init` has to be declared, thus `Holder<T>` is also declared.

The standard demands that when a template class is instantiated, its deleted member functions are defined. **[temp.spec]**

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes: [...]
>
> —— The implicit instantiation of the definitions of deleted member functions, unscoped member enumerations, and member anonymous unions.

And a reference to `void` should result in a compile error.

We can use this to test whether a specific template is specialized or not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <int& T, typename U> struct NonTypeParameter { 
    U& f() = delete;
};

//internal implementation
int lala = 0;
template <typename T> struct Holder {
    T& f() = delete;
    static int init;
};
template <typename T> int Holder<T>::init = lala++;

//tool for user 
template <typename T> struct InitCRTP {
    using dummy = NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init, void>;
};

class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit> {};//user register easily
int main() {
    std::cout << lala << std::endl;
}
```

This code would compile because `NonTypeParameter<Holder<T>::init, void>` is only declared, not instantiated.

But if we change `class WantInit : public InitCRTP<WantInit>` into

```cpp
class WantInit : public InitCRTP<void>
```

Fails to compile in MSVC, g++ and clang.

This is because the declaration of `NonTypeParameter<Holder<void>::init, void>` needs the implicit instantiation of `Holder<void>`.

The problem OP has encountered is solely due to MSVC's ignorance of `Holder<T>::init` being ODR-used:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <int& T> struct NonTypeParameter { };

int lala = 0;

template <typename T> struct Holder {
    static int init;
};

template <typename T> int Holder<T>::init = lala++;

int main() {
    NonTypeParameter<Holder<int>::init> odr;
    std::cout << lala << std::endl;
}
```

MSVC would output `0`. This means it doesn't realize that `Holder<int>::init` has been ODR-used.

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/z/ZKmiYD)